# how to oauth1 Wp plug-in revoke/reset.?

Tags: plugins, database, authentication

Am using [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api-oauth1/) plugin to gives access to a app-backend dashboard for android/iOS apps. I authorized it and every thing was fine but apps were not working so for troubleshooting I generated another Client ID and Secret key. Now am unable to generate new token for this key or delete the older one or revoke access to the app-plugin entirely.

Getting following error

```
{"code":"json_oauth1_consumer_mismatch","message":"Token is not registered for the given consumer","data":{"status":401}}
```

I tried deleting both plugins from ftp *(app and oauth1)*. Also tried dropping database tables of them but plugin data still exists. Now I cannot reset my entire site for this so any insight would be helpful.

Comment: Your best bet would be to check with the plugin developer's official support channel.  This is a really specific issue and third-party plugins are technically off topic.